# Is it possible to define global compile tasks (e.g. file-extension-dependent) for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I set up a tasks.json file to build my C code in VS Code, which also includes a problem matcher.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "gcc",
    "args": ["-Wall", "-o", "${fileBasenameNoExtension}", "${fileBasename}"],
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "cpp",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "severity": 4,
            "message": 5
        }
    }
```

Since I use variable substitution for the source file and the executable, it would work as portable solution for comfortable compilation of single source files. Unfortunately, VSC requires the tasks.json to be defined separately for each project, i.e. each folder. Is there any way to derive the suitable build task from file extension globally for any file?